# what are the different factors (other than 1) of number containing following primes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

Q. If $a_1,a_2,a_3 ......a_n+1  $ be $ ( n + 1 ) $ different prime numbers, then the number of different factors (other than $1$) of a number of the the form $ N = a_1^m a_2a_3.....a_{n+1})$,

1) $m +1$

2) $ (m+1)2^n$

3) $m.2^n + 1 $

4) None of these

Only one option is correct

---

I thought , I can chose $a_1$ in $(m+1)$ ways being alike and others can be selected in $(1+1)........n$ times $= 2^n$) hence using multiplication principle option 2nd will be correct but that is wrong and I do not why it is wrong. The answer is 4th option. There is no explanation of answer in the book. Please tell me then what will be the answer.

Comment: We want the number of factors of $N$ *other than* $1$.

Comment: Good job, you just missed a little detail.

Comment: Stupid question.  Badly worded and seems to have been made deliberately to trap students into missing the "other than one".  And to not giving a reason is ... well... chicken-####.  I'd get another text book.  You are smarter than the person who wrote the book.  Anyway, the correct answer is $(m+1)*2^n - 1$.